# does flash use sessions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

when you use the flash object to pass a message to the next view, does it use sessions for this? i.e. in a multi-server environment, this will cause issues

Comment: Multi-server environments do not pose a problem.  The rails default is to use cookie-based sessions, so all session data is stored client side.  If you have sensitive information that should not be stored on the client, you can use memcached as a session backend that is fast and accessible to all of your application servers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Yes, it does use session.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash)